# Are SQL transactions finished before a planned failover?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, failovercluster

If I'm failing over my server due to a OS patch, are in-process transactions allowed to finish before stopping the SQL service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Transaction state is "incomplete" or "uncommitted"

When the SQL Server Instance starts, it goes through recovery to redo completed/undo uncommitted transactions

All work is deferred to start up because the reasons for SQL Server shutdown can be many and varied. This isn't known at start up: so redo/undo always happens

Comment: So all transactions in the buffer pool since the last checkpoint are lost, correct?  I would have thought that sql would run a checkpoint before shutting off.

Comment: A Checkpoint isn't a commit: it flushes dirty pages to disk

Answer (score 1):

Either using cluster administrator to manually failover or having a cluster failure it's all the same.  As the databases are brought online on the new node they will go through a recovery where completed transactions are rolled forward and incomplete transactions are rolled back.